# Arduino Convert std:string to String

Tags: serial, c++, string

I'm working on BLE project with espressif library. And It returns me founded BLE device.

```
std::string getManufacturerData();
std::string getName();
int         getRSSI();
BLEScan*    getScan();
```

When I want to print device name to serial port

```
BLEAdvertisedDevice founded_dev;
founded_dev=foundDevices.getDevice(0);
Serial.println("Name -> " + founded_dev.getName());
```

It gives me error like this

```
no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::println(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)'
```

So how can i convert to std:string to String in Arduino?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't. Instead just access the underlying C string:

```
Serial.print(F("Name -> "));
Serial.println(founded_dev.getName().c_str());
```

Comment: That works for getName() but not some of the other methods such as `BLEAdvertisedDevice::getAddress()` or `BLEAdvertisedDevice::getServiceUUID()`

Comment: @TomAuger That's because they don't return a string.  The first returns a BLEAddress, the second a BLEUUID. Custom types that will need special handling.

Comment: For the UUID you can use `getServiceUUID().toString().c_str()`, For the address you can use: `getAddress().toString().c_str()`.